# How to run a command/code on the end user/client machine using MS Team bots

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am developing a Bot using node.js in MSBot framework and deployed the same in MS Teams channel and it is working fine. My requirement here is , i need to run a command/code on the end user/client machine using MS Team bots.

Comment: One possible solution would be to have your users install a helper program on their machine and use the bot to send triggers to that application.

Comment: @JasonSowers: Any clue on how to achieve this.?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but from a security point of view, running code or a command on the end-user machine is absolutely prohibited and impossible

Comment: Main purpose of this Bot is to perform troubleshooting in the end-user machine.. For Ex: Whenever the user clicks the button it has to perform that operation.(If user presses Ipconfig button, it should display the ipconfig), it there any possibility to achieve this. Currently the same is working in a Emulator for one desktop and in teams as well. But whenever I deploy the same manifest in other teams machine , it is executing the command in source machine only, is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear. Waht is currently working? You are making this ipconfig? Did you mean on your bot code side, because on the client side it's simply a consumer of messages, no code can be executed

Comment: Hi @Nicholas : For Example, If user clicks Flush DNS button, function will be called and below code will be executed                                                           
     if (option =="Flush DNS"){
            
            console.info("Executed option is Flush DNS");
            endpoint = '/todo/api/v1.0/tasks/2'
        }

Comment: once the above code is executed it will call the python endpoint and execute the below command from python                                                                       {
        'id': 2,
         'description': u'ipconfig /flushdns'    
    }

Comment: You have to understand that this python code is not running on your client side

Comment: Yes Nicolas, it is running in the node.js server side.